# How can I install JMX::Jmx4Perl on Windows?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to install JMX::Jmx4Perl on ActivePerl on Windows 7. In the CPAN shell, I ran:

```
install JMX::Jmx4Perl
```

but I got a message about missing dependencies:

> Failed 2/7 test programs. 0/70 subtests failed. ROLAND/jmx4perl-1.12.tar.gz 3 dependencies missing (Sys::SigAction,Term::Size,Term::Clui)

How can I install this?

Comment: this is probably Off Topic for stack overflow, because it isn't really about perl, as much as installing a third party piece of software. But if it wasn't, we'd also have a hard time diagnosing a problem for you, without knowing what your error messages was.

Answer (score 0):

At least one of the dependencies, Sys::SigAction, [isn't supported on Windows.](https://metacpan.org/source/LBAXTER/Sys-SigAction-0.23/Makefile.PL#L11) There's a [jmx4perl PPM](https://code.activestate.com/ppm/jmx4perl/) available, but the only versions that build successfully on Windows are several years old.

I think your best shot would be to install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), which provides a UNIX-like environment on Windows. Even if you manage to install JMX::Jmx4Perl in Cygwin, though, things may not work properly.

Comment: Thank you ThisSuitIsBlackNot, i even tried with Cygwin.. not able to get success on that either.. :(

I managed get all other module except (Sys::SigAction). there's no way we  can get that dependency?

Comment: @kumar Did you try running `cpan Sys::SigAction` in Cygwin? [CPAN Testers](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Sys-SigAction+0.23) shows that it builds successfully.

Comment: Thank you ThisSuitIsBlackNot cpan Sys::SigAction in Cygwin did build successfully.   finally install jmx4perl, there was some other  dependency missing i went ahead and install each of one. Cygwin did it magic.

Comment: Atleast first step towards my goal. :-)

Comment: @kumar Great! Glad to hear you got it installed. Hopefully it works properly in Cygwin.

Comment: Hi ThisSuitIsBlackNot, Is it possible to provide me your email ID?

Comment: Hi  ThisSuitIsBlackNot, do you have any experience working in monitoring log file through script?

Comment: @kumar Are you talking about JMX? I've never used it before. But "monitoring log file through script" is pretty broad...if you have a more specific question, feel free to open a new post.

Comment: Hi, ThisSuitIsBlackNot, i just did it.